# Xubuntu 16.04.2 LTS has broken Libreoffice Draw 5.1.6.2

Tags: 16.04, package-management, xubuntu, libreoffice

I've been trying Libreoffice draw on an up-to-date Xubuntu 16.04.2.
The LO version is 5.1.6.2.

When I "Save" or "Save as...", I get a dialog with following:

Libreoffice 5.1.6.2
Error saving document :
General Error.
General input/output error.
[ OK ]

I can click OK, but after that the draw executable becomes useless and does not respond to any clicks or input; it seems totally numb.

I can open other Libreoffice files (spreadsheets, text, ...) without a problem, but draw has become useless.

I must bruteforce-kill the libreoffice draw executable, which forces a 'recovery' next time......with the same peculiar state when saving it.

I have tried this on an 64bit PC and with a 64bit virtual machine; both show exact same behavior.

Something is very terribly wrong with this combination of Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS and Libreoffice draw 5.1.6.2.

I also run a Fedora 26 / Libreoffice 5.3.4.2 that does not have such issues.

I believe this is serious enough to permit a major upgrade of Libreoffice for this LTS release!

Regards,
S.

Comment: Why don't you upgrade your LibreOffice, or install the `snap` version?  The `snap` version is 5.3.4.2

Comment: Use Fedora, I do =)

Comment: The snap version of Libreoffice does not have the language built in that is used as the system and user language (namely Dutch). Therefore the snap version cannot access the Desktop, because the Desktop directory name in Dutch is "Bureaublad"......aargh!
I have tested Ubuntu 17.04, which solves this issue...but that's not an LTS.....

Comment: +1 I can confirm this. The issue is specific to "Save/Save As/Save a Copy" in LibreOffice Draw, as described by OP. In comparison, "Export/Export as PDF" works fine to save documents in non-editable formats.